# how to remove first two elements while calculating checksum with return type is Char

Tags: c#, checksum

i have a sequnece `0001wglod;1;`

while calculating its checksum. `getCheckSum(0001wglod;1;)`

checksum function:

`

```
public char GetChecksum(string command)
{
System.Text.Encoding enc - System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding ("iso-8859-1");

byte [] data = enc.GetBytes(command);

int checksum = 0;
for each (byte checksum_data in data)
{
checksum +=checksum_data ;

}

byte checksum_OR = (byte) (checksum | 0x80);

checksum_OR  &= 0xff;

return (char) checksum_OR  ;
}`
```

it return C285 i want to eliminate C2 from start i just want 85 , how to eliminate C2 for calculated checksum, need help.

Comment: Two questions - Firstly why do you keep rolling back edits to the post that make the code readable? Two - how do you get a four character string returned from a method that has a char return type?

Comment: first i am adding all values using for each loop 
checksum +=checksum_data ;

then i have to OR with 0x80 to my calculated function

then i return it as return (char) checksum_OR  

it give me 4 digits C285 i want only 85 .

Comment: But it *cannot* return you those four characters. Its return type is `char` which means it returns a single `char`. If you are getting `C285` you are clearly doing something to it. Is that a string or is that a number in hex form or something else? You need to provide us code that replicates your problem properly. If I run your code (once fixed) I get an ellipsis character (which converted to an int is 133).

Comment: Here is my string having method for GetChecksum 

string = cmd = (char)2 + "0001" + "wglod" + ";" + Confignumbercombobox.selectedIndex+ ";"+ GetChecksum( "0001" + "wglod" + ";" + Confignumbercombobox.selectedIndex+ ";")+ (Char)3

it return me 02  for (char)2  30  (for 0) 30 (for 0) 30 (for 0) 31(for 1) 77 (for w) 67 (for g)  6C (for l) 6F (for o) 64 (for d) 3B (for ;) 31 (for 1) 3B (for ;) C285 (C285) is calulated checksum 03  for (char)3

numbers in Hex form

Thanks in advance

Comment: I still don't understand where you are getting C285 from. I agree with the hex values for each of your chars but they add up to 0387 in hex (dec 903). What's more no matter what they add up to your method returns a char. There is no possible way that it returns C285. Could you explain where you are seeing C285? Also you should edit extra information into the question so people trying to help don't need to read the comments.

Comment: here is my string 

 string = cmd = (char)2 + "0001" + "wglod" + ";" + Confignumbercombobox.selectedIndex+ ";"+ GetChecksum( "0001" + "wglod" + ";" + Confignumbercombobox.selectedIndex+ ";")+ (Char)3

which is going to write in my txt file. with my above getChecksum code 

it write in my file like below 

STX 0001wglod;1; ETX

when i convert above command in Notepadd ++ to Ascii to Hex it show me like below

02 30 30 30 31 77 67 6C 6F 64 3B 31 3B C285 03

i only want 85

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is with character encoding. Your method is returning `(char)0x85` which is the unicode character for Next Line (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/85/index.htm).

If you look at that page it tells you what that character is in a variety of other encodings. Most importantly is that in UTF-8 it is encoded as 0xC2 0x85 (c285).

So the problem is nothing to do with your method that calculates the checksum, its that once you are getting a byte (0x85) you are converting that to a Unicode character and then encoding that as UTF-8 when you write it to the file.

If you want to write a byte value to a file you should use an appropriate method to do so. Alternatively if you were to read that file in as UTF-8 then you would get the right character at that position (because if you are reading and writing in the same encoding then what you put in and get back will be the same).

So the question you need to ask is does the file need to be correct or does it just need to do the right thing when you read it in and out of a file. Without any more context on what you are doing we can't easily answer this question.

I'd recommend reading up further on both character encodings and writing binary files.

Comment: Thanks for your response,

can you please tell me how to encode as UTF-8 when writing to file?

Comment: Not in brief. Either go read up on character encodings (I'm sure google will give you plenty) or ask a new question about it. I'm not going to tackle a concept of that size in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use unchecked to disable overflow checking and do the checksum addition with the byte data type. This way all calculations stay in the byte range (0x00..0xff).

```
byte GetChecksum(string command)
{
  var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
  var data = encoding.GetBytes(command);
  byte sum = 0;
  unchecked
  {
    foreach (var b in data)
    {
        sum += b;
    }
  }
  sum |= 0x80; // if you really want to have your checksum always be >= 0x80, which isn't part of "traditional" checksum calculation
  return sum;
}
```

EDIT: Updated my code per request of the asker.

Comment: # Ckuri thanks for your response, can you please elaborate with my code sample as i am new in C#

Comment: I have updated my code. As others have pointed out returning a char makes little sense as checksum calculation is done on a byte level.

Comment: Thanks for elaboration , but it gives me checksum in bytes 133 i want in chars

Comment: If you want hex then GetChecksum("0001wglod;1;").ToString("X2") would return "85" as a string. A char can only hold one character, whereas "85" are 2 chars.

Comment: while using char data type how we use .ToString function ?

Comment: You can't directly convert a char to hex, as only (integer) numbers can be expressed as a hex number. And unlike C/C++ in C# a char represents a Unicode character not a number. If the variable ch is a char you could however do ((int)ch).ToString("X2") to get the hexadecimal Unicode representation of a character - int because the char type is a 16 bit type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple loop like this

```
        string in = "C285"; //Your output, for example C285 here. You can convert your sum return to this
        string out="";
        for (int i = 2; i <= in.Count() - 1; i++) {
            out += in[i].ToString();
        }
```

this codes starts to write first string, into second string from 3rd character to next.
hope it helps

Comment: You might want to look into the `Substring` method which you seem to be trying to duplicate here.